# pycharm не принимает none. Выдает ошибку invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

```
itsdict = ["first", 23, 43, 66, "second", 3838, 32, -223, "third", 995, 5, 2]
mydict = {}
currentstring = none
for element in itsdict:
    if(type(element) == str):
    mydict[element] = []
    currentstring = element
else:
    mydict[currentstring].append(element)
print(mydict)
```

Comment: В любом случае код ошибочный. После `if` должен быть ещё отступ. И если `itsdict` окажется пустой и сработает `for ... else:`, то выйдет ошибка, потому что словарь пустой и такого ключа (любого) который записан в `currentstring` в словаре `mydict` нет. А если `istdict` не предполагается никогда пустым, тогда непонятно зачем вообще ветка `else` сделана у `for`, тогда это лишний код. А, или `else` относится тоже к `if` и ей тоже не хватает табуляций, тогда ладно, хотя всё-равно код не очень.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
currentstring = 'None'
currentstring = None
```

оба варианта работают

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло